# Exit after script in SQLPlus?

Tags: linux, oracle, sqlplus

I've been looking everywhere, and the posts suggest to pipe the `echo exit | sqlplus @script.sql` but my script contains PL/SQL statements, that take input, so as soon as the `PROMPT` message is outputted, the `exit` kicks in and the script exits.

Here's the linux call

```
alias sql 'sqlplus -s user/pass'

sql @test.sql
```

The script executes fine and does the `INSERT` in the DB, but then it  just waits for me to type the exit once it executes. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you not able to modify the script?

Answer (score 4):

The obvious thing to do is to modify your script to have `exit` at the end. If you can't do that you can create a temporary file that does it, e.g.:

```
(cat test.sql && echo exit) > /tmp/test_$$.sql
sql @/tmp/test_$$.sql
rm -f /tmp/test_$$.sql
```

The `$$` in the file name is substituted with the current process's ID (PID), so if the script is run twice simultaneously each will get a different file name; and then it's removed at the end. (You can do a protective delete first, or check it doesn't already exist, just in case an earlier removal failed somehow).

Comment: I did have `exit` at the end of the script, but the pl/sql didn't recognise it

Comment: The exit needs to be right at the end of your script, after any PL/SQL (or plain SQL) statements. If your script ends with a PL/SQL block and its terminating `/` then the exit goes *after* that, on a new line.